# FFMPEG cant convert MP4 to MP3 | No MP3 Encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, lame

I'm facing the problem that I cant convert MP4 Videos to MP3 with FFMPEG. 
Every time I try it, I get this error:

```
Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
```

But I installed FFMPEG and LAME with the flags: **--enable-libmp3lame**

So when I'm running:  **ffmpeg -codecs help | grep 'mp3'** in the console I see that the Flags are set but in the list there is still no libmp3lame like it should be:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --extra-ldflags=-L/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/lib/ --extra-cflags=-I/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/include/
WARNING: library configuration mismatch
avutil      configuration: --prefix=/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/ --enable-shared
avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/ --enable-shared
avformat    configuration: --prefix=/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/ --enable-shared
avdevice    configuration: --prefix=/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/ --enable-shared
avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/ --enable-shared
swscale     configuration: --prefix=/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/ --enable-shared
swresample  configuration: --prefix=/var/www/html/Plugins/apps/ --enable-shared
libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
//HERE SHOULD BE LIBMP3LAME
D.A.L. mp3                  MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3 mp3float )
D.A.L. mp3adu               ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3adu mp3adufloat )
D.A.L. mp3on4
```

As someone metioned in [this Ubuntu Thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1614765)

> lame packages won't add mp3 encoding to FFmpeg

So how can I install libmp3lame on Debian so FFMPEG can use it?

Also I already tried to install libmp3lame0 from [Debian Packages](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libmp3lame0) but that also didnt change anything.

Comment: How did you compile / install FFmpeg?

Comment: Both Ubuntu & Debian's ffmpeg packages (libavcodec*) have mp3 encoding thru libmp3lame enabled so what ffmpeg are you using? If self built you didn't enable it.

Comment: @andrew.46 with this tutorial (sorry its german, but you can get how I did it with the command lines provided): https://www.df.eu/forum/threads/49421-Howto-ffmpeg-und-lame-auf-einem-Managed-Server-installieren

Comment: @doug look at my comment above

Comment: ffmpeg version 3.4.4 and lame version 3.99.4

Comment: If I could read german maybe there would be some good reason for such a deficient configure. If I were you I'd cd back to your ffmpeg source & run `sudo make uninstall` to hopefully get rid of it. Either follow this guide https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu or if on 16.04 consider this ppa - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/xerus-media or if on 16.04 > 17.04 you could just use the Ubuntu repo's ffmpeg..

Comment: Your build is broken. There shouldn't be a `library configuration mismatch`. In addition to doug's comments another option is to [download ffmpeg](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and throw it in `/usr/local/bin` (or `~/bin` if you prefer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your build is broken.
Try uninstalling and then installing it using the following method

First install dpendencies

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev \
  libsdl2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo wget zlib1g-dev
```

Now make a directory for the source files that will be downloaded later

```
mkdir ~/ffmpeg_sources
```

Now install this assembler for x86 optimizations used by x264 and FFmpeg

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
cd yasm-1.3.0
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin"
make
make install
```

Then install libmp3lame

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.99/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
tar xzvf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
cd lame-3.99.5
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --enable-nasm --disable-shared
make
make install
```

Then install ffmpeg

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-nonfree
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make
make install
hash -r
```

You may have to restart your device as it sometimes doesn't work otherwise.
After installing go to the directory ~/bin

```
cd ~/bin
```

then in that directory try to run your command for eg.

```
./ffmpeg -i ~/input.mp4 ~/videos/output.mkv
```

PS:In your question where you've mentioned

```
//HERE SHOULD BE LIBMP3LAME
```

libmp3lame will not be there, rather it will be mentioned in the configuration as

```
configuration: --enable-libmp3lame
```

Do let me know if it works or not. :)

Comment: uinstalled ffmpeg and lame (I got 2 ffmpeg installations on my PC I dont know why) after that I installed ffmpeg normal like you explained but only with the flags --enable-libmp3lime. and it all worked by itselfe! Maybe you should add in the end that you have to restart you server because I need to do that in order to get ffmpeg to work after install :)

Comment: Glad it worked, and i've also mentioned for the restarting of  the device.

Comment: Looks like you got most of this from [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu Compile Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: He explained it much better and a lot easier to understand however.